# Node JS redirect by pipe, chrome download instead of play

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've this code for redirect my web to result web

```
            https.get(result, function(file) {

              file.pipe(res);
            });
```

On Firefox all go well, if i redirect pdf or mp4 i see it on web, but, if i use Chrome, when i redirect mp4 it will download instead of play on browser.
On chrome pdf works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

```
var request = require('request');
request(result).pipe(res))
```